# Change numbering of figures in all chapters

Tags: graphics, floats, formatting, numbering, captions

I'm having troubles changing the numbering style of figures in my chapters, the one that appears in the table of figures are displayed as I want but the numbering in the text is not.

The caption of a figure in the text looks like this

[image]

in the table of figures, instead, it looks like this

[image]

How can I set the figure numbering in the text to be like the one in the table of figures? In other words, how should I do to have the figure numbering like Figura 1.1 Figura 1.2 etc

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, labelsep=period, justification=centering, margin=-1cm]{caption}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\listoffigures

\chapter{Fisica Greca}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{zenone.jpg}
  \caption{Zenone}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The figure is this one
[image]

I'm sorry for the real bad formatting of the compiled pdf but I've taken just the necessary pieces of an old report I was writing.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to adjust it, jus needed to substitute `\labelsep=period` with `\labelsep=space` in the caption package specifications.